# What is the difference between structure and function scope in C?

Tags: c, struct

Consider this piece of code

```
   int main(void)
   {
       typedef struct {
           int i;
       } s;

       struct {
           s s;
       } t;

       return 0;
   }
```

It compiles fine. Now take a look at this one

```
   int main(void)
   {
       typedef struct {
           int i;
       } s;

       s s;
       return 0;
   }
```

This code will not compile -

```
‘s’ redeclared as different kind of symbol.
```

Question: Why is it correct to have "s s;" as a declaration inside a structure, but not correct to have this definition inside a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In upper example member `s` is a local to struct. You cannot use it without using `t.s` syntax, so there is no conflict with structure type `s`.

In lower example structure type `s`, and variable `s` are in the same scope, so it is unclear which you are referring to.

Comment: +1 its good. Do you think this things would be mentioned in c standard?

Comment: @Mr.32 Yes, they are mentioned. I think they are actually called identifier namespaces there:  *"each structure or union has a separate name
space for its members (disambiguated by the type of the expression used to access the
member via the . or -> operator);"* (from n1547)

Answer (score 3):

As a `struct` member, the identifier `s` is unambiguous, because you'll always address it as `somestruct.s` or `someptr->s`.